# Cant refresh listview in android - notifyDatSetChanged() doesnt do a thing

Tags: java, android, listview, refresh, notifydatasetchanged

I am building a simple android client to consume a REST api I have made and installed on my server. I successfully hit the relevant endpoint with a GET request and retrieve the data i want. if i press the send post button i can add a new post to the list. I cant seem to refresh this list though, so i have to logout and in again to see the reflected changes.

Here is the code for the relevant classes:

PostsActivity (UI):

```
package com.bitcrunchy.gez.project2;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Random;

/**
 * Created by gerron on 05/03/16.
 */
public class PostsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView lvPosts;
    public Button postButton;

    private PostAdapter adapter;
    private ArrayList<Post> postList;

    public Button getSubmitPostButton() {
        return postButton;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_posts);

        Intent intent = getIntent();

        final String jwt = intent.getStringExtra("jwt");

        lvPosts = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.posts_list);

        postButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        postButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                sendPost("test post!", "test", null, null, null,
                        getApplicationContext(), jwt);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        lvPosts.setItemsCanFocus(false);

        postList = new ArrayList<>();

        //get posts from hitting the api end point and parsing the json HAL response
        this.getPosts(this.getApplicationContext(), jwt);

    }

    public void getPosts(final Context context, final String jwt) {
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this.getApplicationContext());

        final int loggedInUser = 25;
        StringRequest sr = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, "http://www.project.com/api/users/" + loggedInUser + "/posts", new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    JSONObject hal = new JSONObject(response);

                    if (hal.has("_embedded")) {
                        JSONObject embedded = new JSONObject(hal.getString("_embedded"));

                        if (embedded.has("posts")) {
                            JSONArray posts = new JSONArray(embedded.getString("posts"));

                            for (int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject post = new JSONObject(posts.getString(i));
                                PostFactory postFactory = new PostFactory();
                                postList.add(postFactory.getPost(post));
                            }

                            adapter = new PostAdapter(context.getApplicationContext(), postList, postButton);
                            lvPosts.setAdapter(adapter);


                        }
                        if (hal.has("err-msg")) {
                            System.out.println("ERROR : ".concat(hal.getString("err-msg")));
                        }
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    System.out.println("JSON EXCEPTION : " + e.getStackTrace().toString());
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                System.out.println("VOLLEY ERROR : " + error);
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                params.put("Authorization", "Bearer " + jwt);
                return params;
            }
        };
        queue.add(sr);
    }

    public void sendPost(final String text, final String url, String eventId, String groupId,
                         String attachmentId, final Context context, final String jwt) {
        final String event = eventId;
        final String attachment = attachmentId;
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this.getApplicationContext());

        final int loggedInUser = 25;
        StringRequest sr = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "http://www.project.com/api/users/" + loggedInUser + "/posts", new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                getPosts(context.getApplicationContext(), jwt);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                System.out.println("VOLLEY ERROR : " + error);
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("text", text);
                if (url != null) {
                    params.put("url", url);
                }
                if (event != null) {
                    params.put("event-id", event);
                }
                if (attachment != null) {
                    params.put("attachment-id", attachment);
                }
                return params;
            }


            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                params.put("Authorization", "Bearer " + jwt);
                return params;
            }
        };
        queue.add(sr);
    }


}
```

PostAdapter:

```
package com.bitcrunchy.gez.project;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RatingBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by gerron on 12/03/16.
 */
public class PostAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<Post> posts ;
    private Button btn;


    public PostAdapter(Context mContext, List<Post> posts, Button btn) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.posts = posts;
        BinaryImageResolver resolver = new BinaryImageResolver();

    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return posts.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return posts.get(position);
    }


    public void updatePostsList() {
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        return posts.get(position).render(mContext);
    }

}
```

SimplePost:

```
package com.bitcrunchy.gez.project;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

/**
 * Created by gerron on 04/03/16.
 */
public class SimplePost extends AbstractPost {

    public SimplePost(JSONObject postJSON) {
        super(postJSON);
    }

    public View render(Context mContext) {
        View v = View.inflate(mContext, R.layout.simple_post_row_layout, null);

        //get views
        ImageView profileImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.profile_pic);

        TextView username = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.username);
        TextView timeOfPost = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.time_of_post);
        TextView dateOfPost = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.date_of_post);
        TextView postText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.post_text);
        TextView urlView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.url);

        //set view values
        Resources res = mContext.getResources();
        Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.profile_image_dummy);

        profileImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        username.setText("user 0");

        timeOfPost.setText(date);
        dateOfPost.setText(time);
        postText.setText(text);
        urlView.setText(url);
        v.setTag(id);

        return v;

    }



    public void generateFromJSONPost() {
        try {
            JSONObject links = new JSONObject(post.getString("_links"));
            JSONObject sender = new JSONObject(links.getString("sender"));
            getLastLeafFromUrl(sender.getString("href"));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void populateValuesFromLinks() {
        generateIdFromJSONPost();
    }

}
```

AbstractPost:

```
package com.bitcrunchy.gez.project;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * Created by gerron on 16/03/16.
 */
abstract class AbstractPost implements Post {

    JSONObject post;
    int id;
    String text;
    String url;
    String time;
    String date;
    int senderId;
    Bitmap bitmap;
    Map<String,String> dateTime;

    public AbstractPost(JSONObject postJSON) {
        try {
            post = postJSON;
            id = Integer.parseInt(post.getString("id"));
            text = post.getString("text");
            if (post.getString("url") != "null") {
                url = post.getString("url");
            } else {
                url = " ";
            }
            dateTime = MySqlTimeConverter.splitIntoDateAndTime(post.getString("time_of_post"));
            date = dateTime.keySet().toArray()[0].toString();
            time = dateTime.get(date);
            populateValuesFromLinks();
            generateIdFromJSONPost();
            BinaryImageResolver resolver = new BinaryImageResolver();
            //load from api instead

            byte[] decoded = resolver.decodeBase64("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");
            bitmap = resolver.getBitmapFromBytes(decoded);
            bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 42, 42, false);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            System.out.println("JSON Exception : " + e.getStackTrace().toString());
        }
    }

    public void generateIdFromJSONPost() {
        try {
            JSONObject links = new JSONObject(post.getString("_links"));
            JSONObject sender = new JSONObject(links.getString("sender"));
            senderId = getLastLeafFromUrl(sender.getString("href"));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void populateValuesFromLinks() {
        generateIdFromJSONPost();
    }

    public int getLastLeafFromUrl (String senderUrl) {
        String[] urlParts = senderUrl.split("/");
        return Integer.parseInt(urlParts[urlParts.length-1]);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "{id: " + id + ", text: " + text + ", url: " + url + ", time-of-post: " + time.toString() + "}";
    }

    public View render(Context mContext) {
        //do nothing, implement in subclasses.
        return null;
    };

}
```

I have seen people suggesting that i need call `onClickListener()` on the button from WITHIN `getView()` method in post adapter. Obviously postAdapter doesnt HAVE a button, that belongs to the UI,  so i have tried passing a reference to the button into the PostAdapter so that `onClickListener` for button can be set int `getView()`. This does nothing either. my list is definately being updated but i cant get it to refresh the changes.

Please offer any advice you can :)

Comment: can anybody tell me if whether I am wrong to think that if i need to implement a button click listener  within PostAdapter i can just pass the reference in as an argument to the constructor? As far as  i can tell this shouldnt be a problem, but it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

try to use adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() in onResponce

```
 public void getPosts(final Context context, final String jwt) {
    RequestQueue queue =        Volley.newRequestQueue(this.getApplicationContext());

    final int loggedInUser = 25;
    StringRequest sr = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, "http://www.project.com/api/users/" + loggedInUser + "/posts", new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                JSONObject hal = new JSONObject(response);

                if (hal.has("_embedded")) {
                    JSONObject embedded = new JSONObject(hal.getString("_embedded"));

                    if (embedded.has("posts")) {
                        JSONArray posts = new JSONArray(embedded.getString("posts"));

                        for (int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject post = new JSONObject(posts.getString(i));
                            PostFactory postFactory = new PostFactory();
                            postList.add(postFactory.getPost(post));
                        }

                        adapter = new PostAdapter(context.getApplicationContext(), postList, postButton);
                        lvPosts.setAdapter(adapter);


                    }
                    if (hal.has("err-msg")) {
                        System.out.println("ERROR : ".concat(hal.getString("err-msg")));
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                System.out.println("JSON EXCEPTION : " + e.getStackTrace().toString());
            }

     adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() //add here
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            System.out.println("VOLLEY ERROR : " + error);
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            params.put("Authorization", "Bearer " + jwt);
            return params;
        }
    };
    queue.add(sr);
}
```

Comment: yes, thats what ive tried, it shows it in the code. it doesnt work. ive tried playing with it. ive also added notifyDatsetChanged() after the get request aswell as the post request. it still does nothing

Comment: so,  now im confused. i really need to know whether i should be creating the buttons on click listener within the adapters get view method or not. i dont see why i should as the button os outside of the listView,  ie im not putting a button on each list item,  there is just one button that should refreah the list. i must be missing something simple,  but nothing i try refreshes the list

Comment: Rgv - i realise now what you were trying to tell me. however, i tried it andd it does nothing at all. any ideas?